# PHP Radio Button always gives same value

Tags: php, html, email, radio-button

I'm trying to make a simple php radio button that has either a 'yes' or 'no' option, and I want to put the selected option in an email.  Everything seems to work except no matter what I do I always get the 2nd radio option (in this case 'no')!

Here's my code, I've followed every related question and tutorial I can find but I'm a complete beginner with php and coding in general.  Been at this problem for 7 hours today so any help is appreciated.

**I am building the site from a themeforest template, I'm barely a coder

HTML code

```
<form class="contact-form" action="php/send-email-moving-help.php" method="post" novalidate>
  <div class="helper-form-box">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column width-6">
        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-fname form-element large" placeholder="First Name*" tabindex="1" required>
      </div>
      <div class="column width-6">
        <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-lname form-element large" placeholder="Last Name*" tabindex="2" required>
      </div>
      <div class="column width-12">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-email form-element large" placeholder="Email Address*" tabindex="3" required>
      </div>
      <div class="column width-6">
        <input type="tel" name="telephone" class="form-telephone form-element large" placeholder="Phone*" tabindex="4" required>
      </div>
      <div class="column width-6 pt-10">
        <div class="field-wrapper radio-input">
          <p>Can we text you?&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </p>
          <input id="radio-1" class="form-element radio" name="radio-group-1" type="radio" value="yes">
          <label for="radio-1" class="radio-label">Yes</label>
          <input id="radio-2" class="form-element radio" name="radio-group-1" type="radio" value="no">
          <label for="radio-2" class="radio-label">No</label>
        </div>
      </div
    </div>
  </div
</form
```

PHP code

```
$recipient = "my@email.address";

if($recipient === '') {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            FALSE,
            'RECIPIENT_IS_NOT_SET',
            array('error_message'=> 'RECIPIENT email address is not set. Please configure the script.')
        )
    );
}

// Check for empty required field
if(!isset($_POST["email"]) || !isset($_POST["fname"]) || !isset($_POST["message"])) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            FALSE,
            'MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS',
            array('error_message'=> 'MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELDS should not be occurred.')
        )
    );
}

$fname  = filter_var($_POST["fname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lname  = filter_var($_POST["lname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
$radio = $_POST['radio-group-1'];

$email_content = "First Name: $fname\n";
$email_content .= "Last Name: $lname\n";
$email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
$email_content .= "Phone: $telephone\n";
$email_content .= "Can Recieve Texts: $radio\n\n";

// Check if sent
try {
$sendmailResult = mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $headers);
if( $sendmailResult === TRUE ) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            TRUE
        )
    );
} else {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            FALSE,
            'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
            array('error_information'=> error_get_last() )
        )
    );
}
} catch (Exception $_e) {
    returnAndExitAjaxResponse(
        constructAjaxResponseArray(
            TRUE,
            'ERROR_AT_PHPMAIL',
            array('error_message'=> $_e->getMessage())
        )
    );
}

/*
Construct ajax response array
Input: Result (bool), Message (optional), Data to be sent back in array
*/

function constructAjaxResponseArray ($_response, $_message = '', $_json = null) {
$_responseArray = array();
$_response = ( $_response === TRUE ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
$_responseArray['response'] = $_response;
if(isset($_message)) $_responseArray['message'] = $_message;
if(isset($_json)) $_responseArray['json'] = $_json;

return $_responseArray;
}

/*
Returns in the Gframe ajax format.
Input: data array processed by constructAjaxResponseArray ()
Outputs as a html stream then exits.
*/

function returnAndExitAjaxResponse ($_ajaxResponse) {
if(!$_ajaxResponse){
    $_ajaxResponse = array('response'=>false,'message'=>'Unknown error occurred.');
}
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($_ajaxResponse);
die();
}
```

JS that might be related

```
contactForm: function() {
            $(ia).submit(function(a) {
                a.preventDefault();
                var b = $(this),
                    c = b.parent().find(Y),
                    d = b.find(X),
                    e = b.find('input[type="email"]'),
                    f = b.find(Z),
                    g = b.find(_),
                    h = b.attr("action"),
                    i = b.attr("method"),
                    j = [],
                    k = encodeURIComponent(b.find("textarea[name=message]").val() + "\n"),
                    l = [];
                b.find("input:not([type=submit]),select,textarea").each(function(a, b) {
                    var c = $(b),
                        d = c.attr("name");
                    if (c.hasClass("form-aux") && d) {
                        var e = c.data("label") || d,
                            f = c.find("option:selected").text(),
                            g = c.val();
                        !g && c.is("select") ? g = e == f ? "Not selected" : c.find("option:selected").text() : "checkbox" != c.attr("type") || c.prop("checked") || (g = "Not checked"), l.push({
                            name: d,
                            label: encodeURIComponent(e),
                            value: encodeURIComponent(g)
                        })
                    } else d && "message" != d && j.push(d + "=" + encodeURIComponent(c.val()))
                });
                for (var m = 0; m < l.length; m++) {
                    var n = encodeURIComponent("\n") + l[m].label + "%3A%20" + l[m].value;
                    k += n
                }
                j.push("message=" + k), j = j.join("&");
                var o = !1,
                    p = !1,
                    q = !1;
                if (ja = ja.split(".").join(""), d.removeClass(ja), d.each(function() {
                        ($(this).attr("required") || $(this).children().attr("required")) && ($(this).is(":checkbox") ? $(this).is(":checkbox:checked") || (o = !0, $(this).addClass(ja)) : $(this).children().is("select") ? $(this).children().val() == $(this).children().find("option:selected").text() && (o = !0, $(this).addClass(ja)) : $(this).val() || (o = !0, $(this).addClass(ja)), o && c.hide().text(oa).fadeIn(200))
                    }), o || (p = !0), e.val() && !Oa.isValidEmail(e.val()) ? (c.hide().text(pa).fadeIn(200), e.addClass(ja)) : q = !0, "" !== f.val()) return !1;
                if (o && e.val() && !Oa.isValidEmail(e.val()) && c.hide().text(oa + " " + pa).fadeIn(200), p && q) {
                    var r = $(g).val();
                    $(g).css({
                        width: $(g).outerWidth() + "px"
                    }).val(la).attr("disabled", !0), c.hide().text(ka).fadeIn(200), $.ajax({
                        url: h,
                        type: i,
                        data: j,
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).done(function(a) {
                        try {
                            if (a.response === !0) c.text(ma), c.delay(1500).fadeOut(200), d.val("");
                            else {
                                var b = "undefined" == typeof a.json.error_message ? "There is a possibility that your message was not sent. Please check up the server or script configuration." : a.json.error_message;
                                c.hide().text(na + " " + b).fadeIn(200)
                            }
                        } catch (b) {
                            console.log("error in parsing returned ajax data: " + b), console.log(a), c.hide().text("Error occurred. Please see the console for details.").fadeIn(200)
                        }
                    }).fail(function(a, b, d) {
                        console.log("Error occured in processing your request:"), console.log(a), console.log("Text status"), console.log(b), console.log("Error thrown"), console.log(d), console.log("Servre response"), console.log(a.status), console.log("Response Text may contain error output from PHP"), console.log(qXHR.responseText), c.hide().text(na + " (Please see the console for error details.)").fadeIn(200)
                    }).always(function() {
                        $(g).css({
                            width: ""
                        }).val(r).attr("disabled", !1)
                    })
                }
            })
        },
        isValidEmail: function(a) {
            var b = new RegExp(/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i);
            return b.test(a)
        },
```

Comment: Your code seems OK to me. What you see on the screen if you `echo $radio;`?

Comment: where's the form code for this?

Comment: and if you didn't define `$email_content` before, then `$email_content .= "Can Recieve Texts: $radio\n\n";` is failing.

Comment: *"Always put 'no' in my email"* - there's no "mail" related code here and those id's suggests you're using js/ajax/jquery

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to echo $radio, like I said I'm a complete beginner.  I am building the site from a template by themeforest so I'm guessing that's where the issue is coming in?

I do have mail code in there, I didn't include it because there are 15 or so options.

    $email_content = "First Name: $fname\n";

I define email content there, and the email itself sends fine.  I receive a perfectly good email with all of my other form elements (name, select boxes, etc)  The only things that aren't working is this radio button, and a checklist that I haven't tackled with yet.

Comment: there isn't enough code to support this question, IMHO. check for errors; I will pass on this one, good luck.

Comment: I'll add more of my code to support this, not sure how much is too much or too little honestly.  Everything works except the radio button is always returning 'no'.

Comment: Please add your `<form>`, you JavaScript which handles the form validation before submitting the form(if any), your complete php code

Comment: AS I can see, you are using `ajax` to send the form data to php, So please again edit you post and add the related JavaScript to it as well...

Comment: Oh man I'm trying to find it for you but the js file for the template I'm building off of is 8000 lines long, what should I be looking for to find which parts are being used to handle the form validation?

Comment: The reason is that in your javascript you are reading all the `<input>` elements and create the object to send. Then you have 2 elements with same name for your radio button and the one with "No" value is the second one. if you check your `request parameters` in the inspector window, you can see both of the values "Yes" and "No" are sending, but because "No" is the second one, your php is using it as the value. So in your javascript, you have to get only the selected radio button element, not all of them

Comment: Ok I'm trying to follow, I get the gist of what you're saying and that all makes sense but I am not clear how I would change my javascript to only get the selected radio button. I am a step closer and you've been a great help so far, thank you for all your patience

Comment: OK, then I'll post an answer for you if you need?

Comment: Yes that would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: Posted the answer, Please give it a try and see if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in your JavaScript you are collecting all the `<input>` elements and create the object to send. in this line:

```
b.find("input:not([type=submit]),select,textarea").each(function(a, b) {
```

Then you have 2 elements with same name for your radio button and the one with "No" value is the second one. if you check your request parameters in the inspector window, you can see both of the values "Yes" and "No" are sending, but because "No" is the second one, your php is using it as the value. So in your JavaScript, you have to get only the selected radio button and checkbox(if any) element, not all of them.

You only need to change the line I mentioned earlier and exclude all checkbox and radio button elements and then include only checked checkbox and radio button elements like this:

```
b.find("input:not([type=submit],[type=checkbox],[type=radio]),select,textarea,:radio:checked,:checkbox:checked").each(function(a, b) {
```

Comment: I made these changes, but now it doesn't give me anything I'm getting blank text whereas instead of 'no'.  Definitely seems like a step in the right direction

Comment: Have you selected the 'yes' radio button?

Comment: You mean on my form?  I selected the 'yes' radio button and also tried the 'no' button but neither are giving me any output in the email

Comment: Nevermind it is now working!! I had to add back in the 'checked' option so that one button starts checked, but both buttons are working!  You are the absolute best, thank you so much for you help!!

Comment: @cheesecake28 :) You are welcome, if this answer has helped you to solve your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it and also give it an up-vote

Comment: Done and done. Seriously you are a life saver, cheers!! 
 edit: my rep is weak so upvote doesnt display publicly but when I accumulate rep i'll be back!

Answer (score -2):

You need to give each radio button a unique name. Because each have the name 'radio-group-1' the second option will override the first.

You can put them in an if statement.

```
if($_POST(['radio-group-1') == 1 {
  $radio = "Yes";
} elseif($_POST['radio-group-2') == 1 {
  $radio = "No";
}
```

Comment: Excuse me? The sole reason to create radio buttons is to give them all the same name! It will make sure only 1 can be selected!

Comment: You're confusing radio buttons with normal checkboxes.